# INSERT key on primefaces input

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this inputText field

```
<p:inputText value="#{simController.simuForm.xNumber}"
    id="xNumber" maxlength="11"
    converter="stringToBigDecimal">
    <p:ajax process="@this" partialSubmit="true" 
        event="blur"
        listener="#{simController.handlexNumber}" 
        update=""/>
</p:inputText>
```

when I put in a number, it looks ok, but when I press the INSERT key the value changes to a negative number.

[image: positive]

to

[image: negative]

How can I disable the key for all inputs?

Comment: So this works normally with an `h:inputText` and `f:ajax`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this `p:remoteCommand` in the page you want to disable the INSERT key in all the inputs

```
<p:remoteCommand oncomplete="$('input').on('keydown',(e)=> {if(e.keyCode == 65)return false;})" autoRun="true" />
```

if you want to do it for a specific input just change the jquery selector.